# Python Splitting a file into many files and adding in extra info

Tags: python, text, split

I am looking to split 2 text files and combine them as so:

So the first file is called 'Names.txt' and is a list of names. It's extremely large and so manually putting the names into the next part is a no go:

```
Chloe
Megan
Harry
etc...
```

The second file is called 'Attributes.txt' and is a list of SETS of attributes separated by $$$$:

```
attribute1
attribute2
attribute3
$$$$
attribute1
attribute2
etc...
```

A set of attributes each relate in order to the names in the first file. HOWEVER I do not know many attributes are in each set as it is random.

I want to take the first name from the first file and the first set of attributes from the second file and write them to a new file:

```
Chloe
attribute1
attribute2
attribute3
```

And then loop it so that it does the second name and set and so on...

So far I have this code:

```
import os
input_file1 = open('Names.txt', 'r')
input_file2 = open('Attributes.txt', 'r')
lines1 = input_file1.readlines()
def group_by_person(some_source):
    buffer = []
    for line in (some_source):
        if line.startswith("$$$$"):
            if buffer: yield buffer
            buffer = [line]
        else:
            buffer.append(line)
    yield buffer
i = 0
name1 = lines1[i]
name2 = name1[:-1]
g = 0
while os.path.exists(name2 + '%s.txt' % g):
    g += 1
with open(name2 + '%s.txt' % g, 'w') as f:
    with input_file2 as source:
        for lines2 in group_by_name(source):
            f.write(lines2[i])
            i += 1
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a good quality question! There's only one thing missing: what happens when you run your code. Obviously it doesn't produce the desired output, otherwise you wouldn't have asked, but does it produce the wrong output, crash or burn? :)

Comment: Hi, well i get an error "IndexError: list out of range". It does write a new file with the correct name but with the attributes for the second person, and it doesn't loop at all.

Comment: What's your error? If it's a crash, you usually get a lot of debug information (a stack trace, for example) that is very helpful for finding out what went wrong.

Comment: In order: read, split, zip. Join and write out. Look them up.

Comment: line 24, in <module> f.write(lines2[i]).  "IndexError: list out of range."

Comment: This particular line does not exist in the code you posted :) It says `lines2[1]`, not `lines2[i]`.

Comment: Sorry it was supposed to be lines2[i].

Comment: This is not the code you are running.  You have function named `group_by_person`, but you call a function named `group_by_name`.  Please copy-and-paste your *actual* code.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey ben, check my answer, if you don't understand some part of the code let me know I will explain.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help Maresh, I'm getting an error on line 12: [Erron 22 invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'Chloe\n0.txt' I think this is because the file name it is trying to create includes the "\n" at the end of the name and this is forbidden. How can i make it remove the "\n"?

Comment: Call n.rstrip() to remove the newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's what you're trying to achieve, comment if I'm wrong:

```
def group_by_person(names_file, attributes_files):
    with open(names_file) as names, open(attributes_files) as attributes:
        for name in names:
            line = [name.strip()]
            for attribute in attributes:
                if attribute.startswith("$$$$"):
                    break
                line.append(attribute.strip())
            print line
            yield line

names_count = {}

for name in group_by_person('Names.txt', 'Attributes.txt'):
    n = name[0]
    names_count[n] = names_count.setdefault(n, 0) + 1
    with open("%s%s.txt" % (n, names_count[n]), 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(name))
```

Test results:

Names.txt:

```
Chloe
Megan
Chloe
```

Attributes.txt:

```
attribute1
attribute2
attribute3
$$$$
attribute4
attribute5
$$$$
attribute6
```

Outfiles:

```
Chloe1.txt, Megan1.txt, Chloe2.txt
```

Chloe1:

```
Chloe
attribute1
attribute2
attribute3
```

Megan1.txt

```
Megan
attribute4
attribute5
```

Chloe2.txt:

```
Chloe
attribute6
```

I believe that's conclusive

Final edit.

Comment: This isn't very close. OP doesn't hard code file names in `group_by_persons` and OP is also concerned about clashing names in output files.

Comment: Ye well, I believe he can change the function to add extra parameters by himself... That's not really the point

Comment: And output files won't clash as you add the iteration number to the filename. (unless you run that as batches, then you need a stronger system or remember the previous bad last iteration number.)

Comment: OP's code had clashing name "uniquifiers" to advance by 1 per name, but you've added the iteration number to all of them.

Comment: Thank you so much Maresh! Works like a dream!

Comment: Accept my answer please. Do you understand the code?

Comment: Yeah I understand what you have done. Think I need to look a bit more closely at generators.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is hard to read and understand. Try to split it to logical parts. You used generator for `group_by_person` what is nice solution. How about to create same generator to get persons? After that you can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) function to aggregate persons and groups. Here's what i mean:

```
def persons():
    with open('Names.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if line: yield line

def groups():
    with open('Attributes.txt', 'r') as f:
        group = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if line == '$$$$':
                if group: yield group
                group = []
            else:
                group.append(line)
        if group: yield group


for person, group in zip(persons(), groups()):
    print(person, group)
```

Output:

```
Chloe ['attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3']
Megan ['attribute4', 'attribute5']
Harry ['attribute6', 'attribute7', 'attribute8']
```

Now all the task is to write it to files and check for cases, when not every person got set of attributes.

Comment: That's no complete though, he has other concerns. Which apparently deserves a downvote... You won't get that from me tho.

Comment: @Maresh it's easy to write least of code, but shouldn't we try to help him to solve problem but not to solve it instead of him?

Comment: I agree. Tried that. Got down votes... Will up u ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
with open("Names.txt") as namefile, open("Attributes.txt") as attfile:
    names = namefile.read().split("\n") 
    attributes = attfile.read().split("\n$$$$\n")

pairs = list(zip(names, attributes))
```

Each pair now associates a name with the attributes in the corresponding position, and you can process it further to format it however you like.